# identity server 3 - idserver and web server in different time zones

Tags: identityserver3

I would like to understand the behaviour of the id_token and access_token expiry times a little better. When my IdServer is located in the UK and the Web server is in the US, and consider a user accessing the web application through browser from singapore, my id_token and access_tokens are valid for 60 mins as per the client configuration. Is this still valid or will there be issues since the idserver and web server are in different time zones?

Currently i can see that the authentication is successful but i am not sure when the token expires.

Comment: Regardless of time zones, 60 minutes last equally long in the US, UK and Singapore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have verified that the token expiry is working fine as it should.

The technical explanation goes here.

Inspect the received id_token and access_token at http://jwt.io

They have the two values -

```
auth_time : some running number

exp: some running number.
```

decoding these 2 values at https://www.epochconverter.com/, we can verify the expiry of the tokens.